# I have a garage heater but I don't want it to run at all if the temperature outside is above 45 degrees

Tags: thermostat, outdoor

I was thinking about putting two thermostats in series so that I could set the garage temp to ~65° but ONLY have it come on in the event that the outdoor temp falls below ~45°.

The garage does get a little heat from the house, so it's not too bad in there until the outside temp gets really cold.

This is a great idea in theory, my problem is that I can't seem to find a thermostat that allows me to set a temp below 50°, that is suitable for installation oustide. I'd prefer an electronic one rather than quicksilver in a jar, but it also has to be weatherproof.

Comment: So if it is 46 degrees in the garage and outside, you don't want any heat?

Comment: Have you priced operation of this garage heater?  You might want to do that before deciding to run it automatically at all times.

Comment: Confused. You want the inside of your garage to be 65 degrees when it is 44 degrees outside but NOT 65 degrees when it is 47 degrees outside?  What is the reason for this?

Comment: is there a reason you want the garage heated at all when you're not working in it?

Answer (score 1):

Your idea of having two thermostats will probably work, but the thermostat you are searching for might need a little help.  There are two ideas I have.  First, a heat pump system needs a thermostat outside so the compressor doesn't run when it's too cold outside.  Thermostats such as the [Goodman OT18-60A](https://hvacdirect.com/goodman-outdoor-heat-pump-thermostat-ot18-60a.html) perform that function.  Now, that is designed to cut off the power when the temperature is too low, but that in conjunction with a "normally on" relay might work for you.

The other thing you could search for is thermostats for pool or spa equipment.  Pool freeze protection relies on an outdoor thermostat, so you might find something there.